# Root Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge running Android 5.1.1

Tags: rooting, 5.1-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-6

Is there a way to root this device? Its model name is SM-G925F. PingPong Root works only with Android 5.0.2.

Comment: Follow this tutorial to root 5.1.1 devices

How to Root edge 5.1.1.
http://galaxys6root.highonandroid.com/galaxy-s6-root/how-to-root-galaxy-s6s6-edge-on-android-5-1-1/
But remember rooting can cause to brick your phone so proceed at your own risk

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing the stock Recovery with its respective TWRP Recovery and then flashing the SuperSU though the TWRP Recovery.

Next are the download links_

- [TWRP Recovery](https://twrp.me/Devices/): Type the model of your device (Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge), select the correct version of your device and then download the image.
- Last version of [SuperSU](https://download.chainfire.eu/696/SuperSU/): Will give you root access
- [Odin](http://odindownload.com/): You'll use it to flash the TWRP recovery

Here's a guide for rooting Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 7" Wifi. Even though the device is different, the steps should be the same you just need to use the TRWP specific for your device and the latest version of SuperSU (more change of success). [Guide](https://techbeasts.com/2015/05/13/install-twrp-recovery-root-galaxy-tab-4-t230-t235/)

I've rooted devices up to 4.4 but haven't tried this method with any 5.X device so please tell me if it worked.

**EDIT**

Here a very similar [guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s6-edge/development/twrp-recovery-2-8-7-1-g925f-android-5-1-t3144866) but specific to your device.